# Installing VirtualBox on CentOS 7

Tags: virtualbox, centos7, cloud-foundry

`error: file /lib/modules/3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64/kernel: No such file or directory`

This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).

Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

```
yum install devel-
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
yum install devel

vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
error: file /lib/modules/3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64/kernel: No such file or directory
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
```

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run

> > /sbin/vboxconfig

as root.

Comment: Kindly help me how to install virtualbox on CentOS 7 for cloud foundry

Comment: Didi you try it installing it as root?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable the secure boot option and try to install the virtual box in CentOS. I've also tried the following command with root but it didn't solve the problem. After disabling the secure boot option in bios fixed the problem.

```
/sbin/vboxconfig
```